# How to count of a members used invites?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");

exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
  msg.guild.fetchInvites().then(davs => {
    let davetler = davs.filter(dav => dav.inviter.id === msg.author.id).toString()
    console.log(davetler.uses)
    msg.channel.send(`Sunucumuzda ${davs.size} adet davet bulunuyor.\n`)
  })
};

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: true,
  aliases: ["davetler"],
  permLevel: 0
};

exports.help = {
  name: "davet",
  description: "",
  usage: "c!davet"
};
```

This is my code. I want to log to console the sum of the used invites, but it logs to console uses of ALL the invites.

Briefly, I want the sum of the all used invites. If you have any idea, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

This will get you a collection of used invites:

```js
msg.guild.fetchInvites().then(davs => {
  // Filter out unused invites
  const davetler = davs.filter(dav => dav.uses > 0);

  // Or if you only want used invites by the message author
  // const davetler = davs.filter(dav => dav.uses > 0 && dav.inviter.id === msg.author.id);

  // Size of the collection only containing used invites
  console.log(davetler.size);

  msg.channel.send(`Sunucumuzda ${davs.size} adet davet bulunuyor.\n`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of filter, use a map and an if conditional to sum the uses.

```js
let sum = 0
davs.map(dav => {
    if(dav.inviter.id === msg.author.id) {
        sum += dav.uses
    }
})
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Yeah reduce would work too but now I'm questioning if I interpreted the desired outcome right, I think yours might be the answer he wanted.

Comment: It logs `1` to console but I invited more than one?

Comment: @Kaan this solution logs the number of times invites have been used.  If you want the number of invites created and used at least once then use Chris Satchell's answer.  Your original description wasn't clear enough as to the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

davelter its a collection of user invites,because 1 user can have many invites so you cant use `toString()` method here.
The right way is:

```
exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
    msg.guild.fetchInvites().then(davs => {
      let davetler = davs.filter(dav => dav.inviter.id === msg.author.id)
      let invitesUses = 0;
      davetler.map(invite => invitesUses+=invite.uses)
      msg.channel.send(`Sunucumuzda ${invitesUses} adet davet bulunuyor.\n`)
    })
}
```

Comment: `.forEach` would be more appropriate than `.map` in your suggestion.